# How to use a custom response file for a C# program in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My understanding is that VS creates its own response file when building projects.  I would like it to also use a custom response file I create for a C# program.  I've read that response files must have a .rsp extension and contain the same syntax that would be used on a command line.

If what I have said above is true,

1. Where do I put my response file?
2. Does VS handle my response file or its default response file first?

I've read the Microsoft documentation regarding response files but it was not clear to me regarding the above issues.

Comment: what kind of project?

Comment: Sorry - A C# Forms project.  I've edited the post.